# Get age/experience/..from year and month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of years right now and with the current year I got the difference between the two, all fine here but right now I was thinking to be more precise and add the months too and I can't quite think of a way of doing this.

Here's what I have so far:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/rwd32o5a/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1989</li>
    <li>1991</li>
    <li>2004</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var custom = [
    ' years old', ' years of experience', ' years of learning'];
var i = 0;

$('ul li').each(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var y = (d.getFullYear());
    var year = $(this).html();
    var diff = (y - year);

    $(this).html(diff + custom[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % custom.length;
});
```

I want to change my list like this [adding the month]:

```
<ul>
    <li>8/1989</li>
    <li>10/1991</li>
    <li>4/2004</li>
</ul>
```

..and I wanna make it output :

- 26 years 1 month(s) old
- 23 years 11 month(s) of experience
- 11 years 5
  month(s) of learning

Comment: You might find this page useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532932(v=vs.94).aspx. Also look at the `Date.parse()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwd32o5a/2/) you have a working Fiddle

The JS:

```
$('ul li').each(function () {
    // Get the current date of the loop (mm/yyyy) and split it
    var current = $(this).html().split('/');
    var year = current[1]; // Get the year
    var month = current[0] // Get the month

    // Get the current real time
    var d = new Date();
    var y = (d.getFullYear());
    var m = (d.getMonth() + 1); // Add one to the month, because .getMonth() is zero indexed
    var yDiff = (y - year);
    var mDiff = (m - month);

    // Now, if the month difference is negative, add 12 months to it and substract 1 year.
    if (mDiff < 0) {
        mDiff = mDiff + 12;
        yDiff--;
    }

    $(this).html(mDiff + ' month(s) and ' + yDiff + custom[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % custom.length;
    //Thats it!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a **rough** estimate with a little division and modulus.

```
var startDate = new Date("1995").getTime()/1000;
var endDate = new Date("june 1999").getTime()/1000;
var diff = endDate - startDate;

var totalYears = Math.floor(diff/365);
var totalMonths = Math.floor(diff/30);

var y = totalYears;
var m = totalMonths % 12;

console.log('time: ' + y + ' year(s) and ' + m + ' month(s)');
```

Outputs: `time: 4 year(s) and 5 month(s)`